# Restrict delete statement on certain table in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, delete

I have a problem where my customers are complaining that records get deleted even though I see all id's are correct in that table, just to make sure everything is like it should be, is there a way to disable delete statement for one certain table in postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
REVOKE DELETE ON someTable FROM roleOfCustomers;
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way could be using [RULES](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-update.html).

For example:

```
CREATE RULE someTable_do_not_delete AS ON DELETE TO someTable DO INSTEAD NOTHING;
```

*Note*. When using ON DELETE DO INSTEAD NOTHING  the code which is executing   DELETE will not get notified that nothing happened ,as per the client side the DELETE will be successful.